# Find User's First Post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sorting, facebook-fql, feed, status

Using the Graph API or FQL, is there a way to efficiently find a user's first post or status?  As in, the first one they ever made?

The slow way, I assume, would be to paginate through the feed, but for users like me who joined in 2005 or earlier, that would take a very long time with a huge amount of API calls.

From what I have found, we cannot obtain the date the user registered with Facebook for a good starting point, and we cannot sort by date ascending (not outside of the single page of data returned) to get the oldest post on top.

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use facebook query language (FQL) to get first post information.

Please refer below query for more details :-

```
SELECT message, time FROM status WHERE uid= me() ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

Please check and let me know in case of any issue.

Thanks and Regards
Durgaprasad

Comment: Hi, this does not seem to work. It doesn't give the first status, I've been able to get an older one with this query but it still isn't the first one :/

SELECT message, time FROM status WHERE uid = me() ORDER BY status_id asc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 140

Answer (score 1):

I think the Public API is limited to the depth of information it is allowed to query.  Facebook probably put in these constraints for performance and cost concerns.  Maybe they've changed it.  When I tried to go backwards thru a person's stream about 4 months ago, there seemed to be a limit as to how far back I could go.  Maybe it's a time limit or a # posts back limit.  If you know when your user first posted, then getting to it should be fairly quick using the since/until time stamps in your queries.

Comment: _"If you know when your user first posted, then getting to it should be fairly quick[...]"_


Thank you, but that's really the part I'm asking about.  I _don't_ know when the user first posted, and that's what I would like to be able to figure out.

Comment: As stated above, your maybe stuck and have no viable solution to this unless you can "guestimate" or even ask your user, when they first posted so you can go fishing for that stream item.  Happy hunting!